# cmake linker error: undefined reference to `sf::Color::Color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'

Tags: c++, linker, sfml, tmx

I am sure this has probably been answered elsewhere before... however, I have been unsuccessful in finding the location. Cmake issues have been the primary factor for me being stuck on tools that take care of these things for you (Visual Studio, QT, Code::Blocks) but I am really trying to make a move off of them.

This projects compies and runs perfectly in Code::Blocks btw.
I am trying to link SFML and TMXLITE, however I am getting this linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/mov.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
/home/kevin/source/repos/mov/src/main.cpp:61: undefined reference to `sf::Window::isOpen() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kevin/source/repos/mov/src/main.cpp:64: undefined reference to `sf::Window::pollEvent(sf::Event&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/mov.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `MapLayer::Chunk::Chunk(tmx::TileLayer const&, std::vector<tmx::Tileset const*, std::allocator<tmx::Tileset const*> >, sf::Vector2<float> const&, sf::Vector2<float> const&, sf::Vector2<unsigned int> const&, unsigned long, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture, std::default_delete<sf::Texture> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture, std::default_delete<sf::Texture> > > > >&, std::map<unsigned int, tmx::Tileset::Tile, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, tmx::Tileset::Tile> > > const&)':
/home/kevin/source/repos/mov/src/SFMLOrthogonalLayer.hpp:193: undefined reference to `sf::Color::Color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/mov.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `MapLayer::Chunk::generateTiles(bool)':
/home/kevin/source/repos/mov/src/SFMLOrthogonalLayer.hpp:276: undefined reference to `sf::Vertex::Vertex(sf::Vector2<float> const&, sf::Color const&, sf::Vector2<float> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kevin/source/repos/mov/src/SFMLOrthogonalLayer.hpp:276: undefined reference to `sf::Vertex::Vertex(sf::Vector2<float> const&, sf::Color const&, sf::Vector2<float> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kevin/source/repos/mov/src/SFMLOrthogonalLayer.hpp:276: undefined reference to `sf::Vertex::Vertex(sf::Vector2<float> const&, sf::Color const&, sf::Vector2<float> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kevin/source/repos/mov/src/SFMLOrthogonalLayer.hpp:276: undefined reference to `sf::Vertex::Vertex(sf::Vector2<float> const&, sf::Color const&, sf::Vector2<float> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/mov.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `MapLayer::createChunks(tmx::Map const&, tmx::TileLayer const&)':
/home/kevin/source/repos/mov/src/SFMLOrthogonalLayer.hpp:544: undefined reference to `sf::Color::Color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mov.dir/build.make:101: mov] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/mov.dir/all] Error 2
```

Here is a copy of my Cmake file:

```
project(mov)
SET(PROJECT_NAME mov)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build (Debug or Release)" FORCE)
endif()

SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules/")
SET(PROJECT_STATIC_RUNTIME FALSE CACHE BOOL "Use statically linked standard/runtime libraries?")
SET(PROJECT_STATIC_TMX FALSE CACHE BOOL "Use statically linked tmxlite library?")

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR APPLE)
  if(PROJECT_STATIC_RUNTIME)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++14 -static")
  else()
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++14")
  endif()
endif()

SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -D_DEBUG_")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O4 -DNDEBUG")

find_package(TMXLITE REQUIRED COMPONENTS tmxlite)
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED COMPONENTS graphics window system)

include_directories(
  ${TMXLITE_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(PROJECT_SRC src/main.cpp)

if(WIN32)
  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 ${PROJECT_SRC})
else()
  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SRC})
endif()

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${TMXLITE_LIBRARIES}
  ${SFML_LIBRARIES})

#install executable
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION .)

#install game data
install(DIRECTORY assets
  DESTINATION .)
```

and my TMXLite module:

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

```
# Search for the header file
find_path(TMXLITE_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES /usr/local/include/Config.hpp PATH_SUFFIXES include)

# Search for the library
find_library(TMXLITE_LIBRARIES NAMES TMXLITE PATH_SUFFIXES lib)

# Did we find everything we need?
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(TMXLITE DEFAULT_MSG TMXLITE_LIBRARIES TMXLITE_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

SFML module (coppied from web):

```
# This script locates the SFML library
# ------------------------------------
#
# Usage
# -----
#
# When you try to locate the SFML libraries, you must specify which modules you want to use (system, window, graphics, network, audio, main).
# If none is given, the SFML_LIBRARIES variable will be empty and you'll end up linking to nothing.
# example:
#   find_package(SFML COMPONENTS graphics window system) // find the graphics, window and system modules
#
# You can enforce a specific version, either MAJOR.MINOR or only MAJOR.
# If nothing is specified, the version won't be checked (i.e. any version will be accepted).
# example:
#   find_package(SFML COMPONENTS ...)     // no specific version required
#   find_package(SFML 2 COMPONENTS ...)   // any 2.x version
#   find_package(SFML 2.4 COMPONENTS ...) // version 2.4 or greater
#
# By default, the dynamic libraries of SFML will be found. To find the static ones instead,
# you must set the SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES variable to TRUE before calling find_package(SFML ...).
# Since you have to link yourself all the SFML dependencies when you link it statically, the following
# additional variables are defined: SFML_XXX_DEPENDENCIES and SFML_DEPENDENCIES (see their detailed
# description below).
# In case of static linking, the SFML_STATIC macro will also be defined by this script.
# example:
#   set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)
#   find_package(SFML 2 COMPONENTS network system)
#
# On Mac OS X if SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES is not set to TRUE then by default CMake will search for frameworks unless
# CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK is set to "NEVER" for example. Please refer to CMake documentation for more details.
# Moreover, keep in mind that SFML frameworks are only available as release libraries unlike dylibs which
# are available for both release and debug modes.
#
# If SFML is not installed in a standard path, you can use the SFML_ROOT CMake (or environment) variable
# to tell CMake where SFML is.
#
# Output
# ------
#
# This script defines the following variables:
# - For each specified module XXX (system, window, graphics, network, audio, main):
#   - SFML_XXX_LIBRARY_DEBUG:   the name of the debug library of the xxx module (set to SFML_XXX_LIBRARY_RELEASE is no debug version is found)
#   - SFML_XXX_LIBRARY_RELEASE: the name of the release library of the xxx module (set to SFML_XXX_LIBRARY_DEBUG is no release version is found)
#   - SFML_XXX_LIBRARY:         the name of the library to link to for the xxx module (includes both debug and optimized names if necessary)
#   - SFML_XXX_FOUND:           true if either the debug or release library of the xxx module is found
#   - SFML_XXX_DEPENDENCIES:    the list of libraries the module depends on, in case of static linking
# - SFML_LIBRARIES:    the list of all libraries corresponding to the required modules
# - SFML_FOUND:        true if all the required modules are found
# - SFML_INCLUDE_DIR:  the path where SFML headers are located (the directory containing the SFML/Config.hpp file)
# - SFML_DEPENDENCIES: the list of libraries SFML depends on, in case of static linking
#
# example:
#   find_package(SFML 2 COMPONENTS system window graphics audio REQUIRED)
#   include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
#   add_executable(myapp ...)
#   target_link_libraries(myapp ${SFML_LIBRARIES})

# define the SFML_STATIC macro if static build was chosen
if(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES)
    add_definitions(-DSFML_STATIC)
endif()

# define the list of search paths for headers and libraries
set(FIND_SFML_PATHS
    ${SFML_ROOT}
    $ENV{SFML_ROOT}
    ~/Library/Frameworks
    /Library/Frameworks
    /usr/local
    /usr
    /sw
    /opt/local
    /opt/csw
    /opt)

# find the SFML include directory
find_path(SFML_INCLUDE_DIR SFML/Config.hpp
          PATH_SUFFIXES include
          PATHS ${FIND_SFML_PATHS})

# check the version number
set(SFML_VERSION_OK TRUE)
if(SFML_FIND_VERSION AND SFML_INCLUDE_DIR)
    # extract the major and minor version numbers from SFML/Config.hpp
    # we have to handle framework a little bit differently:
    if("${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR}" MATCHES "SFML.framework")
        set(SFML_CONFIG_HPP_INPUT "${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR}/Headers/Config.hpp")
    else()
        set(SFML_CONFIG_HPP_INPUT "${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR}/SFML/Config.hpp")
    endif()
    FILE(READ "${SFML_CONFIG_HPP_INPUT}" SFML_CONFIG_HPP_CONTENTS)
    STRING(REGEX MATCH ".*#define SFML_VERSION_MAJOR ([0-9]+).*#define SFML_VERSION_MINOR ([0-9]+).*#define SFML_VERSION_PATCH ([0-9]+).*" SFML_CONFIG_HPP_CONTENTS "${SFML_CONFIG_HPP_CONTENTS}")
    STRING(REGEX REPLACE ".*#define SFML_VERSION_MAJOR ([0-9]+).*" "\\1" SFML_VERSION_MAJOR "${SFML_CONFIG_HPP_CONTENTS}")
    STRING(REGEX REPLACE ".*#define SFML_VERSION_MINOR ([0-9]+).*" "\\1" SFML_VERSION_MINOR "${SFML_CONFIG_HPP_CONTENTS}")
    STRING(REGEX REPLACE ".*#define SFML_VERSION_PATCH ([0-9]+).*" "\\1" SFML_VERSION_PATCH "${SFML_CONFIG_HPP_CONTENTS}")
    math(EXPR SFML_REQUESTED_VERSION "${SFML_FIND_VERSION_MAJOR} * 10000 + ${SFML_FIND_VERSION_MINOR} * 100 + ${SFML_FIND_VERSION_PATCH}")

    # if we could extract them, compare with the requested version number
    if (SFML_VERSION_MAJOR)
        # transform version numbers to an integer
        math(EXPR SFML_VERSION "${SFML_VERSION_MAJOR} * 10000 + ${SFML_VERSION_MINOR} * 100 + ${SFML_VERSION_PATCH}")

        # compare them
        if(SFML_VERSION LESS SFML_REQUESTED_VERSION)
            set(SFML_VERSION_OK FALSE)
        endif()
    else()
        # SFML version is < 2.0
        if (SFML_REQUESTED_VERSION GREATER 10900)
            set(SFML_VERSION_OK FALSE)
            set(SFML_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
            set(SFML_VERSION_MINOR x)
            set(SFML_VERSION_PATCH x)
        endif()
    endif()
endif()

# find the requested modules
set(SFML_FOUND TRUE) # will be set to false if one of the required modules is not found
foreach(FIND_SFML_COMPONENT ${SFML_FIND_COMPONENTS})
    string(TOLOWER ${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT} FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_LOWER)
    string(TOUPPER ${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT} FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER)
    set(FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_NAME sfml-${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_LOWER})

    # no suffix for sfml-main, it is always a static library
    if(FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_LOWER STREQUAL "main")
        # release library
        find_library(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_RELEASE
                     NAMES ${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_NAME}
                     PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib
                     PATHS ${FIND_SFML_PATHS})

        # debug library
        find_library(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DEBUG
                     NAMES ${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_NAME}-d
                     PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib
                     PATHS ${FIND_SFML_PATHS})
    else()
        # static release library
        find_library(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_STATIC_RELEASE
                     NAMES ${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_NAME}-s
                     PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib
                     PATHS ${FIND_SFML_PATHS})

        # static debug library
        find_library(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_STATIC_DEBUG
                     NAMES ${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_NAME}-s-d
                     PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib
                     PATHS ${FIND_SFML_PATHS})

        # dynamic release library
        find_library(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DYNAMIC_RELEASE
                     NAMES ${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_NAME}
                     PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib
                     PATHS ${FIND_SFML_PATHS})

        # dynamic debug library
        find_library(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DYNAMIC_DEBUG
                     NAMES ${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_NAME}-d
                     PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib
                     PATHS ${FIND_SFML_PATHS})

        # choose the entries that fit the requested link type
        if(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES)
            if(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_STATIC_RELEASE)
                set(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_RELEASE ${SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_STATIC_RELEASE})
            endif()
            if(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_STATIC_DEBUG)
                set(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DEBUG ${SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_STATIC_DEBUG})
            endif()
        else()
            if(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DYNAMIC_RELEASE)
                set(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_RELEASE ${SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DYNAMIC_RELEASE})
            endif()
            if(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DYNAMIC_DEBUG)
                set(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DEBUG ${SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DYNAMIC_DEBUG})
            endif()
        endif()
    endif()

    if (SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DEBUG OR SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_RELEASE)
        # library found
        set(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_FOUND TRUE)

        # if both are found, set SFML_XXX_LIBRARY to contain both
        if (SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DEBUG AND SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_RELEASE)
            set(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY debug     ${SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DEBUG}
                                                          optimized ${SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_RELEASE})
        endif()

        # if only one debug/release variant is found, set the other to be equal to the found one
        if (SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DEBUG AND NOT SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_RELEASE)
            # debug and not release
            set(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_RELEASE ${SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DEBUG})
            set(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY         ${SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DEBUG})
        endif()
        if (SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_RELEASE AND NOT SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DEBUG)
            # release and not debug
            set(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DEBUG ${SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_RELEASE})
            set(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY       ${SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_RELEASE})
        endif()
    else()
        # library not found
        set(SFML_FOUND FALSE)
        set(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_FOUND FALSE)
        set(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY "")
        set(FIND_SFML_MISSING "${FIND_SFML_MISSING} SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY")
    endif()

    # mark as advanced
    MARK_AS_ADVANCED(SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY
                     SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_RELEASE
                     SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DEBUG
                     SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_STATIC_RELEASE
                     SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_STATIC_DEBUG
                     SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DYNAMIC_RELEASE
                     SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY_DYNAMIC_DEBUG)

    # add to the global list of libraries
    set(SFML_LIBRARIES ${SFML_LIBRARIES} "${SFML_${FIND_SFML_COMPONENT_UPPER}_LIBRARY}")
endforeach()

# in case of static linking, we must also define the list of all the dependencies of SFML libraries
if(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES)

    # detect the OS
    if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Windows")
        set(FIND_SFML_OS_WINDOWS 1)
    elseif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Linux")
        set(FIND_SFML_OS_LINUX 1)
    elseif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "FreeBSD")
        set(FIND_SFML_OS_FREEBSD 1)
    elseif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
        set(FIND_SFML_OS_MACOSX 1)
    endif()

    # start with an empty list
    set(SFML_DEPENDENCIES)
    set(FIND_SFML_DEPENDENCIES_NOTFOUND)

    # macro that searches for a 3rd-party library
    macro(find_sfml_dependency output friendlyname)
        # No lookup in environment variables (PATH on Windows), as they may contain wrong library versions
        find_library(${output} NAMES ${ARGN} PATHS ${FIND_SFML_PATHS} PATH_SUFFIXES lib NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH)
        if(${${output}} STREQUAL "${output}-NOTFOUND")
            unset(output)
            set(FIND_SFML_DEPENDENCIES_NOTFOUND "${FIND_SFML_DEPENDENCIES_NOTFOUND} ${friendlyname}")
        endif()
    endmacro()

    # sfml-system
    list(FIND SFML_FIND_COMPONENTS "system" FIND_SFML_SYSTEM_COMPONENT)
    if(NOT ${FIND_SFML_SYSTEM_COMPONENT} EQUAL -1)

        # update the list -- these are only system libraries, no need to find them
        if(FIND_SFML_OS_LINUX OR FIND_SFML_OS_FREEBSD OR FIND_SFML_OS_MACOSX)
            set(SFML_SYSTEM_DEPENDENCIES "pthread")
        endif()
        if(FIND_SFML_OS_LINUX)
            set(SFML_SYSTEM_DEPENDENCIES ${SFML_SYSTEM_DEPENDENCIES} "rt")
        endif()
        if(FIND_SFML_OS_WINDOWS)
            set(SFML_SYSTEM_DEPENDENCIES "winmm")
        endif()
        set(SFML_DEPENDENCIES ${SFML_SYSTEM_DEPENDENCIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
    endif()

    # sfml-network
    list(FIND SFML_FIND_COMPONENTS "network" FIND_SFML_NETWORK_COMPONENT)
    if(NOT ${FIND_SFML_NETWORK_COMPONENT} EQUAL -1)

        # update the list -- these are only system libraries, no need to find them
        if(FIND_SFML_OS_WINDOWS)
            set(SFML_NETWORK_DEPENDENCIES "ws2_32")
        endif()
        set(SFML_DEPENDENCIES ${SFML_NETWORK_DEPENDENCIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
    endif()

    # sfml-window
    list(FIND SFML_FIND_COMPONENTS "window" FIND_SFML_WINDOW_COMPONENT)
    if(NOT ${FIND_SFML_WINDOW_COMPONENT} EQUAL -1)

        # find libraries
        if(FIND_SFML_OS_LINUX OR FIND_SFML_OS_FREEBSD)
            find_sfml_dependency(X11_LIBRARY "X11" X11)
            find_sfml_dependency(LIBXCB_LIBRARIES "XCB" xcb libxcb)
            find_sfml_dependency(X11_XCB_LIBRARY "X11-xcb" X11-xcb libX11-xcb)
            find_sfml_dependency(XCB_RANDR_LIBRARY "xcb-randr" xcb-randr libxcb-randr)
            find_sfml_dependency(XCB_IMAGE_LIBRARY "xcb-image" xcb-image libxcb-image)
        endif()

        if(FIND_SFML_OS_LINUX)
            find_sfml_dependency(UDEV_LIBRARIES "UDev" udev libudev)
        endif()

        # update the list
        if(FIND_SFML_OS_WINDOWS)
            set(SFML_WINDOW_DEPENDENCIES ${SFML_WINDOW_DEPENDENCIES} "opengl32" "winmm" "gdi32")
        elseif(FIND_SFML_OS_LINUX)
            set(SFML_WINDOW_DEPENDENCIES ${SFML_WINDOW_DEPENDENCIES} "GL" ${X11_LIBRARY} ${LIBXCB_LIBRARIES} ${X11_XCB_LIBRARY} ${XCB_RANDR_LIBRARY} ${XCB_IMAGE_LIBRARY} ${UDEV_LIBRARIES})
        elseif(FIND_SFML_OS_FREEBSD)
            set(SFML_WINDOW_DEPENDENCIES ${SFML_WINDOW_DEPENDENCIES} "GL" ${X11_LIBRARY} ${LIBXCB_LIBRARIES} ${X11_XCB_LIBRARY} ${XCB_RANDR_LIBRARY} ${XCB_IMAGE_LIBRARY} "usbhid")
        elseif(FIND_SFML_OS_MACOSX)
            set(SFML_WINDOW_DEPENDENCIES ${SFML_WINDOW_DEPENDENCIES} "-framework OpenGL -framework Foundation -framework AppKit -framework IOKit -framework Carbon")
        endif()
        set(SFML_DEPENDENCIES ${SFML_WINDOW_DEPENDENCIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
    endif()

    # sfml-graphics
    list(FIND SFML_FIND_COMPONENTS "graphics" FIND_SFML_GRAPHICS_COMPONENT)
    if(NOT ${FIND_SFML_GRAPHICS_COMPONENT} EQUAL -1)

        # find libraries
        find_sfml_dependency(FREETYPE_LIBRARY "FreeType" freetype)
        find_sfml_dependency(JPEG_LIBRARY "libjpeg" jpeg)

        # update the list
        set(SFML_GRAPHICS_DEPENDENCIES ${FREETYPE_LIBRARY} ${JPEG_LIBRARY})
        set(SFML_DEPENDENCIES ${SFML_GRAPHICS_DEPENDENCIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
    endif()

    # sfml-audio
    list(FIND SFML_FIND_COMPONENTS "audio" FIND_SFML_AUDIO_COMPONENT)
    if(NOT ${FIND_SFML_AUDIO_COMPONENT} EQUAL -1)

        # find libraries
        find_sfml_dependency(OPENAL_LIBRARY "OpenAL" openal openal32)
        find_sfml_dependency(OGG_LIBRARY "Ogg" ogg)
        find_sfml_dependency(VORBIS_LIBRARY "Vorbis" vorbis)
        find_sfml_dependency(VORBISFILE_LIBRARY "VorbisFile" vorbisfile)
        find_sfml_dependency(VORBISENC_LIBRARY "VorbisEnc" vorbisenc)
        find_sfml_dependency(FLAC_LIBRARY "FLAC" flac)

        # update the list
        set(SFML_AUDIO_DEPENDENCIES ${OPENAL_LIBRARY} ${FLAC_LIBRARY} ${VORBISENC_LIBRARY} ${VORBISFILE_LIBRARY} ${VORBIS_LIBRARY} ${OGG_LIBRARY})
        set(SFML_DEPENDENCIES ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES} ${SFML_AUDIO_DEPENDENCIES})
    endif()

endif()

# handle errors
if(NOT SFML_VERSION_OK)
    # SFML version not ok
    set(FIND_SFML_ERROR "SFML found but version too low (requested: ${SFML_FIND_VERSION}, found: ${SFML_VERSION_MAJOR}.${SFML_VERSION_MINOR}.${SFML_VERSION_PATCH})")
    set(SFML_FOUND FALSE)
elseif(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES AND FIND_SFML_DEPENDENCIES_NOTFOUND)
    set(FIND_SFML_ERROR "SFML found but some of its dependencies are missing (${FIND_SFML_DEPENDENCIES_NOTFOUND})")
    set(SFML_FOUND FALSE)
elseif(NOT SFML_FOUND)
    # include directory or library not found
    set(FIND_SFML_ERROR "Could NOT find SFML (missing: ${FIND_SFML_MISSING})")
endif()
if (NOT SFML_FOUND)
    if(SFML_FIND_REQUIRED)
        # fatal error
        message(FATAL_ERROR ${FIND_SFML_ERROR})
    elseif(NOT SFML_FIND_QUIETLY)
        # error but continue
        message("${FIND_SFML_ERROR}")
    endif()
endif()

# handle success
if(SFML_FOUND AND NOT SFML_FIND_QUIETLY)
    message(STATUS "Found SFML ${SFML_VERSION_MAJOR}.${SFML_VERSION_MINOR}.${SFML_VERSION_PATCH} in ${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR}")
endif()
```

Current Terminal output is:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -S/home/kevin/source/repos/mov -B/home/kevin/source/repos/mov/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/kevin/source/repos/mov/build/CMakeFiles /home/kevin/source/repos/mov/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/kevin/source/repos/mov/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/mov.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/mov.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/kevin/source/repos/mov/build'
cd /home/kevin/source/repos/mov/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/kevin/source/repos/mov /home/kevin/source/repos/mov /home/kevin/source/repos/mov/build /home/kevin/source/repos/mov/build /home/kevin/source/repos/mov/build/CMakeFiles/mov.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kevin/source/repos/mov/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/mov.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/mov.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/kevin/source/repos/mov/build'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so', needed by 'mov'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kevin/source/repos/mov/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/mov.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kevin/source/repos/mov/build'
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

My OS is ubuntu. I am not sure what I am missing at this point. If anyone could explain where I am going wrong I would really appreciate it!

Thank you!
-Kevin

Comment: Your `find_package(SFML...)` statement is missing the `COMPONENTS` keyword. If that does not fix it, please edit your post with the output of `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: Also note that SFML comes with [CMake support out of the box](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/cmake/SFMLConfig.cmake.in), so I'm not sure why you are using that custom script.

Comment: Hello @Botje! Thanks for the update, I have added COMPONENTS, it seems to have helped a little, I also added the current console output. I am not building SFML itsself, that does have a CMake file, and that was easy to build.
Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: The build process  for SFML *also* generates a `SFMLConfig.cmake` that is loaded when you `find_package(SFML...)`. I have no idea what is wrong with the FindSFML you were given, but I would dump it for the much more modern SFMLConfig that comes with SFML.

Comment: Anyway, I cannot explain the error you get if you installed SFML properly. How *did* you build and install SFML?

Comment: SFML was easy, I installed the dependencies, I cloned the repo, made a "build" folder, ran "cmake ..", ran "make" ran "sudo make install" everything went smooth. I was able to make the code I posted above build and run using Code Blocks. I just want to code with VS Code from now on, that requires me to use CMake for MY projects.

I just added the directories containing my .so files manually, i think i am getting loser!
include_directories(
  #${TMXLITE_INCLUDE_DIR}
  #${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR}
  /usr/local/include/SFML
  /usr/local/include/TMXLITE
  )

Comment: @Botje Success!!! That was the issue, I just updated my compiler and things are working now! Thanks for the help!

Comment: You .. updated your compiler? And that fixed it?

Comment: no, I hard coded the path to my libs